understanding Euler-Bernoulli beam segment curvature distribution and external torque balance
For a cantilevered beam below using Euler-Bernoulli assumption, use $w(x,t)$ to denote the vertical displacement at position $x$ along the beam. At the clamped end,  we have
$w(0, t)=0$ and $\frac{\partial{w}}{\partial{x}}(0,t)=0$. The curvature at position $x$ is roughly proportional to $\frac{\partial^2{w}}{\partial^2{x}}(x,t)$, the picture below showed a smaller curvature at the distal end compared to near end, which means the second derivative at the near end is bigger.  The induced torque is proportional to the curvature, so $T_2$ is bigger than $T_1$, this I can understand.
Could someone help me to understand this sentence?
"The local or induced torque in a bend segment of a beam must have been caused by an external torque of opposite sign, so the total torque is zero"
So $F l_1$ as an external torque compensate the induced torque $T_1$, but how come the same force $F$ can be used twice to compensate the induced torque $T_2=F l_2$?
Actually I have a problem understanding the free-cut trick, the induced torque $T_2$ and $T_1$ can be analyzed using Young modulus along the fiber of the beam by calculating the strain, thus the stress, thus the force, thus the torque. However, the induced force or torque should come from both ends of the segment, without shear force, this end-of-segments force should be parallel to the fiber, how come the orthogonal external force $F$ get transmitted to be parallel end-of-segments force?


Since term "local" is used, I guess the sentence may be about infinitesimally short segment.

I guess your confusion is about mixing the equilibrium of the cross-section stresses and the external torque balance of the beam.
Yes, the sum of external and internal torque is zero at $l_1 ,$ this means the curvature at this point has caused the beam cross-section to stiffen up and resist further bending and has produced an internal torque at section $l_1$.
So at section $l_1$ we have a shear of $F , $ and a torque, $\tau$ of $F*l_1$
The torque and shear at $l_2 $
$$\Sigma \tau \ l_2=F \ (l_2-l_1) +\tau \  l_1 \ =F \ (l_2-l_1)+ Fl_1= F \ (l_2-l_1+l_1)=Fl_2$$
We could cut the beam into as many sections as we want, but the answer is the same when we add all the torques.
Shear at $l_2$ $$V_{l_2}= F$$

so $F(\ell_2-\ell_1)$ assumes the force balance the point force and segment $\ell_1$? This is true if $\ell_1 \rightarrow 0$?

yes. in that case, the torque is $\tau l_2 = Fl_2 +0F=F*l_2$
